# How to clone a xamarin project from git that is missing the binaries?

Tags: git, xamarin, monogame

I have pushed a xamarin monogame project to github, without all the compiled binaries and dependencies (such as the monogame library).
I have created a .gitignore that excludes all these files.

I only push the actual .cs files, the Content folder that contains images, and the .csproj and the .sln solution files (not sure if those two are necessary)

This works, but my question is: how can another user start a fresh new Xamarin Monogame project with these files? If they simply clone the repository, Xamarin won't recognize it as a complete project and will start complaining when you try to open it.

Note: I have tried using Xamarin's native git option, but that seems unreliable and undocumented.

Comment: What does it complain about ? because you would only need .cs .csproj and .sln to have a "complete" project

Comment: Cannot find assembly file. I have now included the Properties folder with assemblyinfo.cs and now it generates the rest automatically.